# Duplicate items in ListView vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove the duplicates in my listview. Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmQuizSelector

Private Sub cmdExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub lvwQuizzes()
    With Me.lvwListOfQuizzes
        .FullRowSelect = True
        .GridLines = False
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("QuizID", 1)
        .Columns.Add("Quiz Title", 268)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub frmQuizSelector_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.cmdPrevQ.Visible = False
    Me.cmdNextQ.Visible = False

    lvwQuizzes()

    Try
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestions"
        AConn.Open()
        Using dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, AConn)
            dataadapter.Fill(dtb)
        End Using
        AConn.Close()
        Me.lvwListOfQuizzes.Items.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To dtb.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim lv As New ListViewItem
            lv.Text = dtb.Rows(i).Item("QuizID1")
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("QuizTitle"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("CourseSubject"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("QuestionNumber"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("ActualQuestion"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("Answer1"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("Answer2"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("Answer3"))
            lv.SubItems.Add(dtb.Rows(i).Item("Answer4"))
            Me.lvwListOfQuizzes.Items.Add(lv)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        AConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub lvwListOfQuizzes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvwListOfQuizzes.Click
    Me.cmdNextQ.Visible = True

    Try
        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE [QuizID1] =  " & lvwListOfQuizzes.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text & ""
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        AConn.Open()
        Using dataadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, AConn)
            dataadapter.Fill(dtb)
        End Using
        AConn.Close()
        For Each row As DataRow In dtb.Rows
            Me.lblQuizName.Text = row("QuizTitle").ToString()
            Me.lblCourseSubject.Text = row("CourseSubject").ToString()
            Me.lblQNum.Text = row("QuestionNumber").ToString()
            Me.lblQuestion.Text = row("ActualQuestion").ToString()
            Me.lblA.Text = row("Answer1").ToString()
            Me.lblB.Text = row("Answer2").ToString()
            Me.lblC.Text = row("Answer3").ToString()
            Me.lblD.Text = row("Answer4").ToString()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        AConn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The above code generates duplicates in my listview. For example I have five quiz titles saying "Countries" in my database (with different questions attached to each of the five titles), my listview shows all of the five same titles. I only need it to show just one since it's just one quiz title

Comment: How would you usually prevent duplicates being added to a list? When you have an item to add, you would compare it to each item already in the list and add it if and only if you find no match. This situation is EXACTLY the same as that. THINK it through, pick up a pen and paper and write down the steps you need to perform and then try to write code to implement those steps.  If you encounter an issue while doing that, THEN would be the time to post a question here. Programming doesn't exist in a vacuum. How you would do things in "real life" is usually how you do them in programming too.

Comment: add items for to an array, use Linq Distinct to filter out duplicate items, then add them to your ListView https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

Since data is assigned to datarows before being poured into a listview, I would suggest preventing duplicates from accessing rows rather than making long researches of data at anytime you inject 'em into listview.

```
Dim lastrow As DataRow
Sub tbnewrow(Objet As DataTable, e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)
        If (e.Action = DataRowAction.Commit) Then
            If (Objet.Rows.IndexOf(lastrow) > 0 AndAlso e.Row.Item(1) = Objet.Rows(Objet.Rows.IndexOf(lastrow)).Item(1)) Then
                e.Row.Item(1) = ""
            Else
                lastrow = e.Row
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

This can assure that the second column doesn't have duplicate rows all stowed repeatedly in one load.

Now just bind this event to your datatable.

```
Dim dtb As New DataTable
AddHandler dtb .RowChanged, AddressOf tbnewrow
```

Following this, you could maybe prefer to use a datagrid instead of listview, this is more time saving.